# Radis: cut dump.rdb for dev purposes

Tags: redis

I have a dump.rdb file with 8GB of data. As redis will be read from RAM, I would like to start the redis-server on my local dev machine with a smaller amount of data.

Is there a possibility to remove about 95% of the keys from the dump.rdb in order to have a testing dump file with only a few thousands of keys instead 8 MiO I have on the production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to fire up a new instance using the full RDB, then delete keys to get down to what you want, then save that RDB and use it on your development machine. There is no native way to alter the RDB file directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native Redis way, but you can do it with [rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools), you can read only keys that follow a pattern and emit them in Redis protocol.

Something like this:

```
rdb.py --command protocol --key "users:*" dump.rdb
```

Will output:

```
*3
$3
SET
$13
users:1824594
$32
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
*3
$3
SET
$13
users:1826324
$32
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This output can be directly fed to your Redis resource with netcat.